# Can't write to S3 bucket using S3.Object function but Cloud Watch logs shows there should be a file there

Tags: aws-lambda

I am trying to write to an S3 bucket using the S3.object() function within a lambda (python).
When I test the lambda and view the cloud watch debug logs, It shows that a json file should be written at the desired dynamic location but when I check the bucket prefix, there is nothing written although my lambda has full S3 bucket access.

> **Here is the output  that should be placed in the json file within the
> bucket**:
> [image]
> **Here's the lambda code snippet:**
> [image]
>
> **Here is the debug file**
> [image]

> **Here is the AWS Console for the bucket prefix**
> [[image]]

> **Here are the permissions for the lambda**

[image]

Comment: `put()` returns a response. Have you tried to print that response? That is what would tell you if something went wrong. Please provide that as well.

Comment: I did get a Response Metadata returned using put: with a return code of 200:                 < S3 OBJECT >>  {'ResponseMetadata': {'RequestId': 'RF7QKMQ783QG13KM', ...}

Answer (score 0):

I have successfully written to a bucket with the following code:

```
import json
import boto3

s3 = boto3.resource('s3')


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    json_data = ['1', '2', '3']
    json_output = '\n'.join(json.dumps(i) for i in json_data)
    response = s3.Object('chadyuk-technologies','year=2023/month=03/day=24/json_result_23-02:12.03.json').put(Body=json_output)
    print(response)
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': json.dumps(json_output)
    }
```

Comment: That should not be a problem.  Indeed, the above code worked equally well.  Did you get the response from the put() method, as requested by Maverick?

Comment: Yes I included it in my problem description above just now  . It gave me a Response Metadata:  {'ResponseMetadata': {'RequestId': 'TN89JRXN1CJ6EQK4', 'HostId': 'ckuDCejzjualZ5n+Bc5i/vAcyEe....}

Comment: I think I'm going to create a dummy  lambda and hardcode values for the output prefix , bucket, and  json output to see if I can add that single piece of data to the dynamically created  prefix.

Comment: @AnthonyWilliams, there is no issue with the code in your screenshot.  I have updated the code in my answer to reproduce every function call in your screenshot and found no issue.  Could you please follow the guideline in https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example to produce deployable code that can reproduce your problem in a clean environment.  Thank you!

Comment: Ok @AlexChadyuk I was able to create test lambda and insert just one like of data and it worked but I  will also try your suggestion and get back to you. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> I found the issue:

I investigated the Bucket Policy to see if there were any sort of access restrictions and sure enough I discovered that the Sid had a `DelegateS3Access` policy on the bucket and the AWS for the Principal was set to a specific Secret Access Key for some user (Whom I am still looking for  in IAM).
Thus what was happening is that whenever I wrote to the desires S3 Bucket and its prefix, ***AWS was duplicating a copy of the prefix in the same bucket***.

> This means that for bucket `dev-cog-cne-mass`  I had 2 prefixes of:

```
data/refined/prospect-api/enrollment/
```

I was only aware of *1 instance* at the time. So, my code was functioning fine but the bucket permissions were causing an issue which I was not aware of. Once I deploy this to Stage and Production I may not have these RW restrictions.